# I have an app on google play and have developed a new version using a different development tool. How do I get this on google play?

Tags: android

My app on google Play needs to be replaced with a new version.
I am having difficulty as I do not have the things I think are required to sign the new version with the same things used for the signing of the one already there.
The app name is the same but the bundle id is not.
Can someone please point me in the direction of a step by step process to achieve this.

Comment: It is similar but I do not have the key codes that were used before and the bundle id is different, the App name is the same.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say. It is then not possible to update it in the Play Store

Comment: If by "the bundle id" you mean the package name, then you can simply upload it as a new app.

Comment: If you want existing users to auto-update, then you need the same package name and to use the existing signing keys.  It's not possible if you don't/can't do both.

Comment: I have made the app name and id the same as before and have raised a request to google for a new key store as I do not have the one I used when I uploaded the previous version.